# I can get the Apple Magic Mouse to pair, but the mouse stays in discover mode

Tags: hardware, mouse, bluetooth, magic-mouse

I've got a Magic Mouse, using an Asus Bluetooth dongle.

This is a description of trying it on Natty a few months ago on a Lenovo laptop with Unity, though trying again on Precise on a desktop with Gnome Shell gives me pretty much the same results. The mouse *does* actually work on Lucid, though I think scroll wasn't supported back then. I try to follow the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleMagicMouse

Though the actual BT preferences wizard diverged slightly at step 6 back when I looked at these instructions for Natty.

- I bring up the BT preferences.
- I turn on my mouse, wait for it to start blinking.
- I click "Set up new device...".
- It finds my mouse.
- I click on PIN options and set it to 0000. (note that in Lucid, I don't do this, instead it comes up as a dialog as it's pairing, which *does not* happen here)
- I select it and click Forward.
- It goes through its process and says it's successfully connected.
- It's now listed as a device in the BT preferences window, but the mouse is still blinking, and doesn't move my cursor.
- There's an icon, I think implying "connected", that stays on until the mouse gives up on discovery mode and shuts off. (the same icon goes away when I click "disconnect" in the preferences window)

If I try the same thing, but leave the pin on "automatic", it does the same thing, except the "connected" icon only stays on for a second.

Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I've abandoned this. I'm no longer running Natty. Works ok on Lucid, haven't tried on Precise yet.

Comment: Why would I delete it though? Perhaps somebody has an answer and it could be useful to somebody else?

Comment: Just tried on Precise Pangolin and failed; updated the description to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

- Installed `blueman` and opened it.
- Right click on listed device and select input device.
- Enter pass phrase as `0000`.

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

An user said to me before that He connects automatically his magic mouse with `Blueman` application.You can install it from Software Center.

Comment: Also make sure you are connecting to the "Input Service" of the device.